# String of numbers and letters - etc. 123E45

Tags: excel

I am working with randomly generated alphanumeric strings. The strings are six characters long. Most of them are fine but I have some that are, for example;

123E45
987432
252627
549E09

When I run my formulas, it comes up with #N/A because it reads them as numbers even though the cells were defined as text and the values pasted in afterwards.

Furthermore, I am not able to use Visual Basic to solve this problem.

Edit: Subsequent to the comments below, I have added an apostrophe to the number strings and it has solved the problem but only for when the strings are pure numbers. I still have problems when there is an 'E' in the string. Some examples;

'274E42
'2522E2
'257E52
'2656E5
'257E33
'224E56
'24E282
'252E92
'24E256
'268E35
'2784E6
'24E237

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

JP

Comment: post some code how do you handle this , how are you generating these strings

Comment: These strings are automatically generated in a database and are given to me to perform data analysis. They are all unique references.

Comment: Can you show the formula which causes the error?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `'` in front of your numbers in order to force excel to handle it as a String, and not as a number.

Comment: Thanks krestano, I may have to do that but it may cause me other problems. I was wondering if there was a quick way round it. I was thinking about using =TEXT(12345,#) or something like that but I don't know what I should it place of the hash.

Comment: Actually, it would probably be best (and easier) to just add the prefix character (e.g. `'` ) to all of the entries or set the column's cell format to **Text**.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I have set the column's cell format to text and it hasn't seemed to work. I set all the relevant columns to text and repasted the values but it didn't change anything

Comment: having `'1` in A1 the formula `=A1+1` will still be `2` even `=ISNUMBER(A1)` is `FALSE`. Without knowing the formula, there is no "real" help to this problem. Also `=TEXT(12345,"@")` may not be helpfull. Having `123E45` to be shown as `#N/A` also can have different reasons than being no number... normally "value-errors" are shown as `#VALUE`

Comment: Hi Dirk, The formula is very simple and works for almost all of the 20000 lines. It only fails on strings made only of numbers or numbers with an E in. 

=IF(A93<>"",INDEX(JPM!B:B,MATCH(Action!A93,JPM!A:A,0)),"")

This is the formula above.

Answer (score 0):

Select the column of numbers and text and choose Data ► Data Tools ► Text to Columns. Pick 🔘 Fixed width,  <kbd>Next</kbd>,  <kbd>Next</kbd>, 🔘 Text,  <kbd>Finish</kbd>.

Alternately, select the entire column and run this sub procedure.

```
Sub everything_to_Text()
    With Selection
        With Intersect(.Parent.UsedRange, .Cells)
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), _
                           DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                           FieldInfo:=Array(0, 2)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I tried that and it didn't work. This is the because there is a formula in A1.

=IF(IF(LEN(F4E!A93)=6,F4E!A93,"")="","",HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://xxx.xxx.xxx",F4E!A93),F4E!A93))

Secondly, I cannot use visual basic at all in this table.

Comment: That might have been a detail to include in your question.